# MCP23017 not seen in the i2c bus

Tags: i2c

I have a  pin multiplexer with a premade board: https://core-electronics.com.au/mcp23017-io-expansion-board-expands-16-i-o-pins.html
My Pi 4 is powered by USB C. The multiplexer is powered with its own power source. It's little LED light is on.
I connected the SCL and SDA pins from the pi to the multiplexer (Pi pins 2 and 3).
If I run `lsmod`, I see that `i2c_bcm2708` is there. I have `/dev/i2c-1` as a valid file.

However, when I run the command `i2cdetect  -y 1` I get nothing:

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Am I missing something? What else can/should I do to debug this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `i2cdetect` doesn't detect the device you have not connected it or you have something wrong, but you haven't explained WHAT you ACTUALLY connected. Why is the multiplexer powered with its own power source?

Comment: I connected the MCP23017 (the multiplexer) to the PI. It has its own power source because it's easier for me that way -- should I try and power it with the PI?

Comment: "I connected the MCP23017 (the multiplexer) to the PI" is meaningless. WHAT you ACTUALLY connect to what. Using external power just seems an unnecessary complication; I have never used one with MCP23017 which can't draw enough to need one.

Comment: I am lost. The MCP23017  is a serial device that works on I2C. I connected it to the PI's I2C pins. Why is my statement meaningless?

Comment: I fail to understand why people ask questions then seem to be reluctant to clarify. If you connected correctly it must work or is faulty. There are only 3 wires. Maybe if you post a photo someone may be able to help.

Comment: Either provide clear photos showing the connections or close the question.

Comment: The question had enough information there to see the problem. Joan, a photo would be a photo of the component I link to, connected to the pi as I described it. It would have given ZERO extra information. Milliways, you clearly failed to understand. on thing: that the grounds should be connected together.

Comment: We understood the problem.  Why do you think Milliways said there are only 3 wires?  We did not answer because we did not like the attitude.

Comment: Please show me which one of my comment had a bad attitude. I am all ears.

Comment: Wait are you saying that you knew what the problem was (the ground wasn't common) but you didn't say so, and instead kept of asking for a photo (?!?), because you didn't like my _attitude_? What is this, kindergarten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your description you write that "red by USB C. The multiplexer is powered with its own power source. It's little LED light is on. I connected the SCL and SDA pins from the pi to the multiplexer (Pi pins 2 and 3)". This is not enough. You also need to connect GND to GND for the communication to work.

Regarding the power, you could just power it from the pi, unless you have a specific reason not to. If the board draws a lot of power, I would use an external power source, but I am not sure that is the case here.

Comment: You are a genius. I figured it out on my own not very long ago. Grounds need to be connected! Thank you!